# Custom Table View Cell w/ background image - width problem

Tags: uitableview, width

I have a custom cell (set up in IB) with a background image of width 320px. The width of the cell is also 320. When I run my app, there is about 5 pixel of white on the right side of the cells. In other words, my image doesn't cover the entire width of the screen. My code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
        static NSString *OffensivePlayerCellIdentifier = @"OffensivePlayerCellIdentifier";
    OffensivePlayerCell *cell = (OffensivePlayerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: OffensivePlayerCellIdentifier];
    if( cell == nil ) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"OffensivePlayer" owner: self options: nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex: 0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of applying the image directly to the background of the cell, I tried adding an image view and applying the image to that. Now it works. Don't know why. Strange behavior.